# Assign a value to Integer between two constant values?

Tags: java, android, random, integer

Lets say I have 3 Integers:

```
int a, b, c;
b = 25;
c = 10;
```

Now I want `a` to be either 25 or 10 but by random not something like:

```
a = b;
```

I want something like in if statement:

```
a = b || c;
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: You should have googled before asking, maybe?

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 maybe I googled it and I didn't find answer? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(Math.random() < 0.5)
    a = 25;
else
    a = 10;
```

`Math.random()` returns a random number from 0 to 1, so if you want a 50% chance of something being true, just check if it's less than (or greater than) 0.5.

Answer (score 4):

one way is to do by taking the millis of time like:

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0){
    a=b;
} else{
    a=c;
}
```

Comment: Unless the resolution of `System.currentTimeMillis` is an even number in which case it'll always use b.

Comment: This will also return the same number multiple times if you query it fast enough (faster than the resolution).

Comment: then you have to use nano secs for that if you using it fast, by the way FYI Math.random() using the same logic to generate the random number just divide it with number to make it between 0 to 1

Answer (score 3):

@immibis' answer is the simplest way to achieve this.

For testability, I would strongly advise that you use an explicit `Random` instance, rather than using `Math.random()`:

```
static int pickRandomValue(Random r, int b, int c) {
  return r.nextInt(2) == 1 ? b : c;
}
```

This allows you to inject a mock `Random` instance, allowing you to fix the behaviour when you need to test specific behaviour. Non-deterministic tests are a pain, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int myRandom = rand.nextInt(2); // will be 0 or 1
if (myRandom == 0) {
   a=b;
} else {
   a=c;
}
```